# CSS3 transformed element not visible in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, transform, perspective

I want to create a perspective tennis court using CSS3. It looks great in Webkit, but in Firefox, the court itself is not visible. Here is the relevant code:

HTML:

```html
<div id="court-color">  
    <div class="court_outer">
        <div class="court"></div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#court-color .court_outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 514px;
    height: 382px;
    background-color: #82b192;
    -webkit-perspective: 474px;
    -moz-perspective: 474px;
    -o-perspective: 474px;
    -ms-perspective: 474px;
    perspective: 474px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50%, 50%;
    -moz-perspective-origin: 50%, 50%;
    -o-perspective-origin: 50%, 50%;
    -ms-perspective-origin: 50%, 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#court-color .court {
    background-color: #4275b3;
    width: 36em;
    height: 78em;
    font-size: 10px;
    border: 0.5em solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -39.5em -18.5em;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 0) translate(0px, -6em);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 0) translate(0px, -6em);
    -o-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 0) translate(0px, -6em);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 0) translate(0px, -6em);
    transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 0) translate(0px, -6em);
}
```

I guess it has something to do with the CSS3 transformation, but I don't see the problem...

This is what it should look like, but the whole court (`<div class="court">`) is not visible in the latest Firefox.

[image: Should look like this in Firefox]

And lastly, here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Szgpy/

Comment: +1 for this being neat.

Comment: Also, have you thought about using SVG for this?

Comment: I got the court to appear on FF 15.01 by removing `-moz-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 0) translate(0px, -6em);` and leaving the unprefixed version of that declaration: http://jsfiddle.net/Szgpy/3/ - though now the pers

Comment: @Adrift I don't see it in your fiddle...I'm wondering if that's because the URLs are relative, and not absolute.

Comment: @crush: Check it now - I keep pasting the wrong fiddles, sorry its  early :p

Comment: @Adrift I still don't see it =[

Comment: Widen the results pane :p

Comment: Altering the `transform` to `scale3d(1, 0.47, 1)` (leaving the other properties as-is) fixes it for me in Firefox but I still don't know why! **Or** just use `scaleY(.47)`

Comment: Still don't see it in Firefox...

Comment: This should work:  http://jsfiddle.net/Szgpy/4/

Comment: lol. I swear it's still not working @Adrift

Comment: @crush: Okay I give up - maybe next time :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in these rules for `#court-color .court`:

```css
-webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 0) translate(0px, -6em);
-moz-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 0) translate(0px, -6em);
-o-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 0) translate(0px, -6em);
-ms-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 0) translate(0px, -6em);
transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 0) translate(0px, -6em);
```

You need to change the third parameter of [`scale3d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#scale3d%28%29) ("the z-component of the scaling vector") from `0` to `1`:

```css
-webkit-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 1) translate(0px, -6em);
-moz-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 1) translate(0px, -6em);
-o-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 1) translate(0px, -6em);
-ms-transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 1) translate(0px, -6em);
transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale3d(1, 0.47, 1) translate(0px, -6em);
```

[fixed jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/KNTEM/)

I'm guessing that when Firefox scales the Z-axis to zero, the element is flattened so much that it doesn't exist any more, but Chrome treats the element as perfectly flat while still displaying it.

Your court will still look the same even when the z-scaling is `1`, because the `div` you're transforming is a 2D object. It's already flat; you don't need to flatten it any further.

Comment: @andyb You're right, [`scaleY()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#scaleY%28%29) would be clearer than `scale3d()`.